# Solving model with CPLEX Concert C#

Tags: cplex

I work with Cplex in C#. my problem is the solving model. I have checked the data and are correct but when I run, the decision variable values that are positive comes negative and some constraints not be observed despite definition. In general, I am not the right answer. It should be mentioned that my code have not an error.

Answer (score 1):

Export the model to an LP file and verify if the same thing happens when you solve that file directly. If the LP file also gives strange results you probably have a bug in the your code that generates the model. Inspecting the LP file may give you information what went wrong. If the LP file works fine, check the status and return codes from your Cplex calls, check the log files carefully and also make sure you are not hitting some kind of a limit (e.g. iteration limit, time limit).

Post was cross-posted [here](https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/13151/cplex-problem-in-c).

Comment: I check the model and realized that one constraint have results to negative values.for this reason, i have comment the constraint but Results not entirely correct. please guide me. thanks

Comment: Same approach: look in the LP file how this equation arrived in Cplex.